# Passing input variables into DBGetQyery in Shiny R

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, shiny

Thank you in advance for thre responses.. The issue i am having i am trying to dynamically retrieve data from an SQLlite database within a Shiny app. I try to pass input variables into some SQL (using paste0) within a dbGetQuery fuction. I keep getting dyntax errors. I was wondering if there is a good way to pass multiple variables into SQL. I am pretty new to databases and shiny, thanks for the help!

```
output$servicerplot <-renderPlotly({

filtersurve <- dbGetQuery(db, statement = 
            paste0("SELECT Year,purpose,Product,seasoning,specPool,Servicer,TPO
                  FROM ServicerScurves
                  WHERE Year =",input$ServYear,
                  "AND purpose =",input$ServPurp,
                  "AND Product =",input$ServProd,
                  "AND seasoning =",input$ServACC,
                  "AND specPool =",input$ServSpec,
                  "AND Servicer =",input$Servicers,
                  "AND TPO =",input$ServTPO))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the programming industry standard of parameterization whenever SQL is called from application layer (Java, Python, C#, PHP, or R) which is supported in [RSQLite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/vignettes/RSQLite.html). Likey the issue is that you are not properly enclosing string variables with quotes. Nonetheless, paramterization avoids any need of concatenation or punctuation.

```
output$servicerplot <- renderPlotly({

   # PREPARED STATEMENT
   sql <- "SELECT Year,purpose,Product,seasoning,specPool,Servicer,TPO
           FROM ServicerScurves
           WHERE Year = ?,
             AND purpose = ?
             AND Product = ?
             AND seasoning = ?
             AND specPool = ?
             AND Servicer = ?
             AND TPO = ?"

   res <- dbSendQuery(conn, sql)

   # BIND PARAMS
   dbBind(res, list(input$ServYear, input$ServPurp, input$ServProd, input$ServACC,
                    input$ServSpec, input$Servicers, input$ServTPO))
   filtersurve <- dbFetch(res)
   dbClearResult(res)

   return(filtersurve)
})
```